# PHP Oracle Update Table Error - oci_execute ORA-00933

Tags: php, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, psql

I've managed to get Select and Create statements working but currently got an issue with Update statements using PHP.

**Result of countryProcessor.php**

```
Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended in /studenthome.hallam.shu.ac.uk/STUDENTHOME8/8/b4025068/public_html/processor/countryProcessor.php on line 60 

CountryID 18
GDP 109
Country Name Australia
Rows Affected 0
```

CountryProcessor.php

```
if(isset($_POST['CountryID'])) {
            $CountryID = $_POST['CountryID'];
        }
        if(isset($_POST['CountryName'])) {
            $CountryName = $_POST['CountryName'];
        }
        if(isset($_POST['Gross'])){
            $Gross = $_POST['Gross'];
        }


        $stmt = oci_parse($conn, "UPDATE COUNTRY SET COUNTRYNAME = '$CountryName', GDP = $Gross WHERE COUNTRYID = $CountryID)");

        // oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":CountryID", $CountryID);
        // oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":CountryName", $CountryName);
        // oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":GDP", $Gross);


        oci_execute($stmt);
        $Affected = oci_num_rows($stmt);
        oci_commit($conn);

        echo "CountryID" . ' ' . $CountryID . "<br>";
        echo "GDP" . ' ' . $Gross . "<br>";
        echo "Country Name" . ' ' . $CountryName . "<br>";
        echo "Rows Affected" . ' ' . $Affected;
        // if(count($Affected) > 0){
        //  header("Location: ../index.php?Success=$CountryName has been updated!");
        // } else {
        //  header("Location: ../index.php?Danger=$CountryName hasn't been updated!");
        // }

        oci_free_statement($stmt);
        oci_close($conn);
```

Comment: There seems to be a typo. Remove the last closing parenthesis in update statement, after $CountryID

Comment: You should also look into using bound parameters instead of injecting unescaped user data directly into your queries. You can see examples [in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-parse.php).

Comment: Thanks, @vmaroli that worked, rookie mistake by me.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson that's how I initially had it set up but since I got the error I changed it to how other forums were doing it.